# Implement CompareAndSwap for bool

Tags: c#, boolean, compare-and-swap

In .NET framework, atomic operation [CompareAndExchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange.aspx) is only defined for `int`, `long`, `double` and reference type. But I need CompareAndExchange for `bool` type. How can I implement `CompareAndSwap` for `bool`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define wrapper boolean values, and use the `CompareExchange` overload for `T where T : class`, like this:

```
private static object TrueObj = true;
private static object FalseObj = false;
...
object val = TrueObj;
object result = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref val, TrueObj, FalseObj);
if (val == FalseObj) { // Alternatively you could use if (!(bool)val) ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice. What I really like about your approach is that there is only a one-time boxing cost.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to dablinkenlight's approach would be to use the `Int32` overload where `0` is `false` and any non-zero value is `true`.